# R Select a data range

Tags: r, dataframe, range

I have a data set with 10 rows and 3 columns. For example:

```
A <- c(5.0, 10.0, 15.5, 20, 22, 25, 30, 
           40, 50, 60)

B <- c(1, 20, 30, 6, 7, 10, 2, 27, 
       3, 10)

Date <- c("1997-05-01","1997-05-02","1997-05-03","1997-05-04","1997-05-05",
          "1997-05-06","1997-05-07","1997-05-08","1997-05-09","1997-05-10")
data <- data.frame(A, B, Date)
```

Thus, I have a data table in R:

```
  A      B     date
----    ----    ----
5.0      1     1997-05-01
10.0     20    1997-05-02
etc...
```

The range is based on quantile. For "A" I wanted < or = to quantile 25 (e.g. 16.625), and B to the > or = to quantile 75 (e.g. 17.50)

```
quantile(data$A, c(.25, .50, .75))

quantile(data$B, c(.25, .50, .75))
```

So, I want to get all of the rows that have a value within a range of the exact values of A and B and create a new data, for example:

The new data would be:

```
  A      B     date
----    ----    ----
10.0    20     1997-05-02
15.5    30     1997-05-03
etc...
```

I would like that the new data had paired data, and not creating columns - A and B - randomly.

how to do that best?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to filter your data frame on those two conditions:

```
data[data$A <= quantile(data$A, 0.25) &
     data$B >= quantile(data$B, 0.75), ]

     A  B       Date
2 10.0 20 1997-05-02
3 15.5 30 1997-05-03
```

The `quantile` function creates a vector of whatever quantiles you specify for your data. If you only care about the 25th or 75th quantile you can just include those single values in the function.

Comment: Thank you very much Warner! One question, how could I create a script to replace the 10 values - A and B paired - with these new values in random order (in this case are two data only)?

Comment: It would be something like this: newdata <- sample(A, din (data) [1] & B, din (data) [3], replace = T)?

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand your question but if you want to replace all the values in `A` that don't satisfy that `<=` condition with random values of A that do you can do `data$A[data$A > quantile(data$A, 0.25)] <- sample(data$A[data$A <= quantile(data$A, 0.25)], replace = TRUE)`. If you have totally different questions I recommend posting a new question rather than asking them in the comments. Hope this helps!

Comment: Also if I answered your question well enough please click the check box  on my answer :]